# Authentication problem - secure web application with API auth server

Tags: security, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, owin, bearer-token

I have started to create a software architecture where i have:

- Auth_API - as an auth server
- Resource_API - as a resource API (protected with Auth_API)
- WebApplication (mvc) - a frontend application (protected with Auth_API).

Based on https://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ article I have successfully made a Google authentication.

WebApp == redirects to ==> Auth_API == challenge ==> Google ==> API receives externalAccessToken, registers user locally and returns **localAccessToken**

Now everything is OK when I would want to use bearer authorization (using local access token).
But I also want to sign in to by ASP MVC application with (cookie?) ClaimsIdentity.

I was thinking about switching to JWT, but I am not sure which way I should go...

**Bit of code:**

1. Auth_API - obtain local access token

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Returns local access token for already registered users
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="provider"></param>
   /// <param name="externalAccessToken"></param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("ObtainLocalAccessToken")]
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ObtainLocalAccessToken(string provider, string externalAccessToken)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(provider) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(externalAccessToken))
       {
           return BadRequest("Provider or external access token is not sent");
       }

       var verifiedAccessToken = await VerifyExternalAccessToken(provider, externalAccessToken);
       if (verifiedAccessToken == null)
       {
           return BadRequest("Invalid Provider or External Access Token");
       }

       IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindAsync(new UserLoginInfo(provider, verifiedAccessToken.user_id));

       bool hasRegistered = user != null;

       if (!hasRegistered)
       {
           return BadRequest("External user is not registered");
       }

       //generate access token response
       var accessTokenResponse = GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse(user.UserName);

       return Ok(accessTokenResponse);
   }
   ```
2. Generate Local Access Token algorythm

   ```
       private JObject GenerateLocalAccessTokenResponse(string userName)
   {
       var tokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

       ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);

       identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
       identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

       var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
       {
           IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
           ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(tokenExpiration),
       };

       var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);

       var accessToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

       JObject tokenResponse = new JObject(
                                   new JProperty("userName", userName),
                                   new JProperty("access_token", accessToken),
                                   new JProperty("token_type", "bearer"),
                                   new JProperty("expires_in", tokenExpiration.TotalSeconds.ToString()),
                                   new JProperty(".issued", ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc.ToString()),
                                   new JProperty(".expires", ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc.ToString())
       );

       return tokenResponse;
   }
   ```
3. Web application - part of login action:

   ```
       if (hasLocalAccount)
       {
           var client = new RestClient(baseApiUrl);
           var externalLoginUrl = "Account/ObtainLocalAccessToken";
           var externalLoginRequest = new RestRequest(externalLoginUrl, Method.GET);
           externalLoginRequest.AddQueryParameter("provider", provider);
           externalLoginRequest.AddQueryParameter("externalAccessToken", externalAccessToken);

           var externalLoginResponse = client.Execute(externalLoginRequest);

           if (externalLoginResponse.IsSuccessful)
           {
               JObject response = JObject.Parse(externalLoginResponse.Content);
               string localAccessToken = response["access_token"].Value<string>();
               string localTokenExpiresIn = response["expires_in"].Value<string>();

               // WHAT TO DO WHERE TO SIGN IN A USER ??? 
               //AuthenticationTicket ticket = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(localAccessToken);   <== this returns NULL

               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
           }
       }
   ```